# When using Firebase.auth, accessToken expire after 1h, how do we get a refreshToken?

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

We are using Firebase with VueJS to manage sign-in to our application. And we also need to access other Google APIs using the `accessToken`, unfortunatly, the token expire after one hour.

```
    import firebase from 'firebase'

    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)
      .then(firebaseUser => {

        var accessToken = firebaseUser.credential.accessToken;
      })
```

How can we renew periodicaly the `accessToken` in order to keep accessing other google API without having to sign-out and sign-in from Firebase ?

I've done some research and i did not find any suitable, simple solution to this issue.

Similar questions

- [Application expires after 1h even when regularly reporting my activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29962400/application-expires-after-1h-even-when-regularly-reporting-my-activity)
- [Retrieve Google Access Token after authenticated using Firebase Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40838154/retrieve-google-access-token-after-authenticated-using-firebase-authentication)

**Edit**
This question is related to the refresh of `accessToken` not `IdToken`

```
firebaseUser.credential: 
   accessToken: "ya29.GlwyBic64v6PW8......"
   idToken: "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImt...."
   providerId: "google.com"
```

Comment: The accepted answer in that question can be applied to yours. Have you tried that?

Comment: 1) I do not think that waiting for the token to generate auth error is the best case senario, i am looking for a better approach to this problem  (2) My question still persist, how can we renew the `accessToken` without having to log-out and log in ?

Comment: Maybe you should be using the Google auth APIs directly rather than relying on Firebase.  https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent

Comment: @DougStevenson Yes, that a possibility, Can you provide more details ? Will the Google Auth API maintain the valid state of the `accessToken`/`refreshToken` ? It seems there is a way to [inject](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/304#issuecomment-307655705) `accessToken`, but how do we retreive the **current** token afterward to persist it between page views ? I need help figuring out the full workflow, and this seems like a question everybody will face.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.  This is definitely not a question "everybody will face".